# Cross Join! In SQL Server, but I really only need about a third of the rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-join

Ok, so I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way. But my scenario is I've got a stored procedure I'd like to test using all the possible combinations of the inputs it takes.

Let's say I have a stored procedure that takes two parameters, like this:

```
set UsefulValue = exec spMyStoredProc @ProfileID, @RoleID
```

Now in my case, ProfileID means something like *people* and RoleID means something like *system* roles. I'm being a little general here on purpose. The point is, I have about 60,000 defined people, and about 600 defined roles.

Unfortunately, the system I'm testing is COMPLICATED, like bad-hair-day complicated, and I **really** need to run this procedure through its paces.

Ok, with me so far? Hopefully you are; check out this sql to generate the data that I will eventually pass to the stored procedure:

```
    select profiles.ProfileID, roles.RoleID from Profile profiles
cross join dbo.DefinedRoles roles
```

This is actually pretty good, but the problem is it's taking forever to run, and frankly I don't need **every** permutation of these two values.

So I tried constricting the result set like so:

```
select top 300000 profiles.ProfileObjID, roles.RoleName from dbo.Profile profiles
cross join dbo.rj_v_DefinedRoles roles
```

But oops! That constricts the final result, so I end up with only a result that is pretty much 2-3 roles (depending on what I pass to the top verb) and with a ProfileID for each person.

What I'd like to have, my **goal**, is to get results for all the roles I have (about 600) and for each one, maybe only use half of the ProfileIDs instead of the whole shebang.

So does that make sense what I'm asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked well. GREATLY cuts down on the time it takes to execute the cross join.

```
select profiles.ProfileObjID, roles.RoleName
from dbo.rj_v_DefinedRoles roles
cross join dbo.Profile profiles
where ProfileObjId in (select ProfileObjId from dbo.Profile
                    where ProfileObjId between 10000 and 11000)
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem you want a number of test cases, but do not want them generated in favour of a specific role / person (which cross join is doing to you).

```
select top 300000
profiles.ProfileObjID, roles.RoleName 
from dbo.Profile profiles 
cross join dbo.rj_v_DefinedRoles roles
order by newid()
```

The order by will randomise your results, then top the results to get a random test set of data. This will not of course guarentee any specific role / person is in the final results, it's a percentage chance etc.

Comment: What prevents the use of `TOP(n)` in the inner query?  (So that the outer query is not required.)  Also, note that the OP asked for a guarantee of *every* Role to come through to the results.

Comment: One thing I tried was to add a WHERE ProfileObjID < 10000 which of course does kinda do what I want. If I could shove a between in there, then wouldn't that allow me to select arbitrary sequential chunks of people to go with roles?

Comment: @TommyFisk - Yes.  Just use `profiles CROSS JOIN roles WHERE ProfileObjID BETWEEN x AND y`

Comment: Dems, that indeed works! Andrew, I want to point out that I got a syntax error (SS complained about order by in a subquery), but this was fixed by declaring another table-valued variable.

Comment: Nothing prevents the top(n) being on the inner query, I was splitting the logic for clarity - I did specifically include in my answer that no guarentee was provided, but in test cases like this, often its a percentage confidence game, in which case this would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ROW_NUMBER() in a couple of different places to select a portion of your data...

```
-- Maximum of 20,000 rows per RoleID
WITH
  combinations AS
(
  SELECT
    roles.RoleID,
    profiles.ProfileID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY roles.RoleID) AS profile_sequence_id
  FROM
    Profile          profiles
  CROSS JOIN
    dbo.DefinedRoles roles
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  combinations
WHERE
  profile_sequence_id < 20000
```

Or...

```
-- Maximum of 20,000 rows per RoleID
WITH
  profiles AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS profile_sequence_id
  FROM
    Profile
)
SELECT
  roles.RoleID,
  profiles.ProfileID
FROM
  dbo.DefinedRoles roles
CROSS JOIN
  profiles
WHERE
  profiles .profile_sequence_id < 20000
```

Comment: Dems, thank you for your answer. It's interesting, but I'm not really familiar with the syntax you're using. I found a simple way, it turns out.

Comment: `WITH xxx AS (SELECT ???) ` is just a way of creating a kind of 'virtual view' or 'virtual temp table' to allow code to be broken into chunks (rather than having nested sub-queries).  But it also allows recursion, allows the 'virtual view' to be joined to itself, and other funky stuff.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY y)` is an analytical or windowing function.  These are relatively new to SQL, and not all vendors support them, though SQL Server 2005+ does.  They're a little more complex than simple SQL, but provide significantly more powerful options.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `DISTINCT` keyword?

select `DISTINCT` profiles.ProfileObjID, roles.RoleName from dbo.Profile profiles cross join dbo.rj_v_DefinedRoles roles

Comment: Isn't the point of a cross join that each row returned is unique? (assuming you execute a vanilla one)

Comment: @TommyFisk - Only if there are no duplicates in the source tables.  Any duplicates in the source is replicated in the result.  So the question becomes: Are both ProfileId and RoleID unique in their respective tables?

Comment: I sort of botched the question a bit, I'm actually using RoleName for now, but will use RoleID in the future. So the answer would be no, more then likely. I ran this query and it was returning very weird results. Definitely don't get DISTINCT apparently.